# crystal report viewer showing blank report

Tags: crystal-reports

I had an application having crystal report in a machine with local sql database, there the report was showing well, but when i copied the same application in another machine having the database file copied in the sql, the application runs fine but the crystal report is showing blank page.
The controls within the application are retrieving the data from the database.

I have created a new ODBC connection.
I have changed the data-source location in the report file according to the new local machine using the ODBC connection.

Comment: Can you check if yo put some static data in the report, does it shoes that? Debugging if its issue with data connection or report display in general.

Comment: i tried and it shows nothing, just a blank report viewer appeares

Comment: Another machine has Crystal Report installed?